# Opener's rebid of 2NT (system: Simple SAYC)

Tags: bridge, bidding

I opened with 1H - Partner bid 2C - (I have 5 hearts, 12 pts, 3spades 3diamonds 2clubs). I have to respond, but responding 2NT would mean I have 18 pts (my written source on this is: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~belk/opening.htm#1.5Notrump: "With 18 or 19 HCP and a balanced hand, you should open in a suit (usually a minor) and then jump to 2NT on your next bid.")

I've been told that in this case (the case where partner responded on 2-level) - 2NT rebid would not mean 18pts (e.g. that it's ok to bid 2nt here). Can someone point me to the appropriate material on the web that discusses this?

Comment: What is your actual hand? Beginners often think that shape and HCP is sufficient, but your actual honors often matter. Do you have a S honor? Do you mostly have Qs and Js or do you have As and Ks? For example, Axx AKJxxx xxx xx is a much stronger hand than xxx AQxxx QJx QJ (in general and especially in this auction).

Comment: The keyword being "jump". After 1H - 2X, 2NT is not a jump...

Comment: @ruds: I never evaluate 14-card hands; I call the director.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Yes, too many spots in the heart suit. I was attempting to illustrate the difference between 3=5=3=2 12-counts. The first hand should have been Axx AKJxx xxx xx

Comment: PLEASE DON'T EDIT QUESTIONS TO MAKE EXISTING ANSWERS OBSOLETE; Unless you **want** to get down-voted that is. Ask a new question, or append to your question if it is a minor variance.

Answer (score 3):

The SAYC card specifies strong jump shifts by responder after a 1H opener, further explaining that it invites a slam. This suggests a 17-19 HCP range with 5+ cards and a good honor holding in the bid suit (though I warn you that point-count is insufficient to evaluate many slam invitational hands, and e.g. AKJxxxx Axx Kx x is a 15-count that suggests a strong jump shift).

Though 2NT only promises a minimum opener as explained by [Aryabhata](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/1224/aryabhata), your first priority must be to show your support for partner's spade suit. Your proper rebid is 4S by the principle of fast arrival. You know enough to sign off: your hand is not good enough to accept a slam invitation (thus the game), and you know your partnership has a spade fit (thus the strain). Bidding 3S here suggests to partner that slam is still a possibility.

If you'd like to read more about opener's rebids after a strong jump shift by responder, [the bridge bum has a good summary](http://www.bridgebum.com/strong_jump_shifts.php).

**Edit** The question has been updated to make the auction start 1H-2C instead of 1H-2S.

SAYC suggests that 1H-2C-2NT should show a balanced hand, 12-14 HCP. Be aware that if the club bidder is an unpassed hand, 1H-2C promises a second bid from responder, and so you're forcing your side to the three level with a 2NT response. You should probably consider a different rebid if your hand doesn't stop the other suits (especially spades, the other major, as defenders prefer to lead majors against no trump contracts).

1H-2C-2H does not promise a 6th heart (as opposed to 1H-1NT-2H or 1H-1S-2H, which do). So if your 5-3-3-2 12-count is something like Jxx AKJxx Qxx Jx, I would rebid 2H. If instead it's AJT KJxxx QJx xx, 2NT seems better.

Comment: thanks for good site link. Please note: I've slightly modified the example in my question (1H-2S --> 1H-2C) it doesn't change the essence of 2nt 18pts rebid (wanted to make the question more succinct).

Comment: I should add that even though 1H-2C-2H doesn't promise 5, it's not a comfortable rebid with 5. I suggest it here because you don't have a 2D rebid or a comfortable 2NT bid.

Answer (score 2):

The ACBL booklet (quick reference) on SAYC can be found here: http://www.acbl.org/documentlibrary/play/sayc_book.pdf.

According to that (page 3), NT rebids by opener at the lowest available level show a minimum hand. (Of course, that probably does not apply when responder initially bids 1NT).

Based on your edit, it looks like you have some confusion regarding what a jump rebid means.

A jump is when you skip a level, i.e. you could have bid the suit/no trump a level lower, but you chose to "jump" over it. For example opener 1D - responder 1S - opener 2NT. 2NT is a jump, as opener could have bid 1NT. In this case, it would indeed show 18-19 balanced hand.

After partner responds 2S, 2NT is not a jump rebid. It is a rebid of NT at the lowest available level.

For more detailed reading, there is also a book by Ellen Pommer, [http://www.amazon.com/Standard-Bidding-With-SAYC-Downey/dp/1897106033](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1897106033) which you might find useful (I haven't read it).

Comment: Oops! I meant to add that comment to my answer, not yours. Please decline edit if desired; I was unable to revert.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: No worries, I have reverted.

Answer (score 2):

A non-jump rebid by opener of 1NT or 2NT shows a balanced 12-14 HCP hand (sometimes with a singleton in responder's suit). A **single-jump** rebid of 2NT or 3NT by opener shows the 18-19 HCP balanced hand.

Partner's jump-shift in spades shows a very good hand, and a very good suit; you should always reveal 3-card support promptly, when you have it, by raising to 3S. If playing fast arrival, the jump-raise to 4S should show a hand both minimum in strength **and** *soft*, ie rich in queens and jacks in short or un-bid suits.

Many partnerships play that a jump by opener is a splinter, showing 4-card support and a singleton in the bid suit; however don't attempt this unless you have already agreed to play splinters in more obvious circumstances. Unlike in my answer yesterday, this is **not** a situation where partner can read it without an agreement.

Questions edited to change auction. This answer addressed the original question.